# Is there a better way to structure these function calls?

Tags: python

I have a class that needs one of a number of helper classes. It will only ever use one of these helpers, and all of them have the same interface. So I'm writing code like this:

```
if self.type == Class.Type.a:
    helper = A()
elif self.type == Class.Type.b:
    helper = B()
elif self.type == Class.Type.c:
    helper = C()

helper.do_stuff()
```

Currently there are about 5 different types, but I can see that expanding, and this structure is already in my class about four or five times, and I can see the need for this logic at least a dozen times.

Is there a better way to perform this logic? I think that Python often uses dictionaries to perform this type of logic, but I don't yet see how that idiom can work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed use a dictionary:

```
my_dict = {Class.Type.a:A,
           Class.Type.b:B,
           Class.Type.c:C}

helper = my_dict[self.type]()
helper.do_stuff()
```